# Ventilation system level 2/3 not working anymore (circuit analysis)

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, fan

A house ventilation system has the following circuit:

[image]

The following three switches enable three levels of fan speed:

[image]

Level 1 is always running, level 2 is intermediate and level 3 is full power.

Recently, when going from 1 to 2, no audible difference is encountered. Activity from both fans should be audible, yet when switching on level 2, no difference can be heared at all. Either (A) one stage of one of the fans has already been broken for a long time, and now stage 2 of the second fan also broke, or (B) there is a problem with the activation of the stages, and the fans are fine.

Level 3 is still working fine.

Assuming that (B) is the case, what could be the reason, according to circuit analysis?

- blau - blue
- schwarz - black
- grün/gelb - green/yellow
- braun - brown
- FROSTSCHUTZSICHERUNG - Anti freeze system
- ABLUFTVENTILATOR - fan for air output
- ZULUFTVENTILATOR - fan for air intake
- CONDENSATOREN - capacitors
- Serienschalter - series switch
- Verteiler - distribution board
- Mantelleitung - sheathed cable

**EDIT: Just colored the first circuit diagram:**
[image: colored circuit low resolution]

Comment: Is this a homework question or, are you an electrician trying to fix something?

Comment: In Germany only the electricians which are allowed to work for a local power grid operator can do the work. Right now it is so that the workload is very high and if you ask your local electrician which is approved to work give you a time-frame which is several month in the future or even next year. The most people can not life with such an error for so long and do it by them self, this is much faster and mostly the problem is very tiny, like a broken capacitor. Replace it, 2-5€ and the system works.

Comment: I am posting this for my father who is somewhat experienced but never understood fully how this system works. This is an actual situation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the unit and take a look onto the screws (luster terminals / Lüsterklemmen), they are possibly not tight enough any more. Tighten them and look if they are damaged somehow.
2. Open the switch and measure the resistance of the contacts. (the system must be without power for this measuring) Change the switch positions so that you are able to measure each contact resistance. If you are using an ordinary multimeter, then hold the two test prods together to determine the initial resistance of the test lead. I suspect that the contacts are boiled or have already worn out and therefore a switch no longer has any effect.
3. Possibly the WRG300 speed control electronic is damaged.

You can measure the capacity of C1, C2, A and B. It looks like they are switching between different capacitors to change the power of the two fans.